# Unable to convert text date into date format

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I guys I am trying to convert a text date, "12/31/9999" to date format using dataflow in einstein
but getting max row failed error. How can i acheive this

```
toDate('textdate',"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is encountering this issue, what I did to make it work is to do it like this in dataflow:

toDate("textdate", "yyyy-MM-dd")